# Using java.util.prefs.Preferences in Jython

Tags: java, linux, jython, preferences

I seem to be having trouble storing Java preferences using a Jython script. If in Jython 2.5 beta I use:

```
clazz = Class.forName('mypackage.myclass')
prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(clazz);
# or Preferences.userRoot()
prefs.put('propertyname', 'yes')
```

The preferences are not stored. If I then add:

```
prefs.flush()
```

I get

> java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.

I am currently running this on Linux and Unix using Java 1.6. I'm hoping that I'm missing something obvious, since my Java applications can successfully use java.util.prefs.Preferences on the same system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to know where it's trying to store the preferences?

Comment: Is it possible that Jython runs as a different user than Java does, one which doesn't have as many permissions?

Comment: I think it's trying to store them in /etc/.java/.systemPrefs

I can't imagine what other user it'd be running as, and I don't want to have to run my script as root. Furthermore, I also don't want to have to set permissions on anywhere in the filesystem since this needs to run well on all OSes.

Comment: On Windows, I believe Preferences uses the registry, so yes, you definitely don't want to assume anything there. Are you using Sun's JDK?

Comment: Yes I am, not the OpenJDK or anything.

Comment: Is is jython-specific problem or you can repeat this problem in pure Java?

Comment: I can't replicate this in pure Java. It always works there. I need to use Jython for this bit.

Comment: if the application is trying to write to /etc/ it must be running as root or .java needs to be writable by the process' user.

Comment: Yes, but I can't require users to change permissions as they may not have access. Also, this seems to work in pure Java. Why not Jython? Does Java run some operations with elevated permissions somehow?

Answer (score 2):

In the comments on your question and the answer you state that it tries to write /etc/.java/.systemPrefs. I don't think that's actually right.

> ```
> clazz = Class.forName('mypackage.myclass')
> prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(clazz);
> # or Preferences.userRoot()
> prefs.put('propertyname', 'yes')
> ```

You are using Preferences.userNodeForPackage, so you will get the .userPrefs.
These are located at /home/[user]/.java and should be writable.

With the systemPrefs you can get permission problems on linux. The preferences are stored in /etc/.java/.systemPrefs by default. If this directory isn't available(if you just copied the jre onto your system for example), the FileSystemPreferences class used to write
the preferences falls back to [java.home]/.systemPrefs.

To call prefs.flush() shouldn't be necessary, since the preferences are saved in a predefined interval and when your program terminates.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed [relevant](http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/bugParade/bugs/4666397.html).

Could it simply be that a file is not created or the owner on the file has insufficient permissions? Or something like that?

Comment: Yes the user doesn't have permissions to write /etc/.java/.systemPrefs

I'm curious if there is some preferences that writes to somewhere normally writable such as the user's home directory.